# ORDER BY DESC with CURDATE(); statement not working in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE(); ORDER BY postDate DESC');
```

I have a simple SQL statement which displays pending records and orders them by DESC but it will not work. However if I delete the "AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE();" statement the DESC will work.

please help!

Comment: remove the semi-colon after your CURDATE()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be no `;` with `CURDATE()`.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY postDate DESC');
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the semicolon after `CURDATE()`, semicolon is the end of the query.

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted 
FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" 
AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE() 
ORDER BY postDate DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwanted semicolon:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE(); ORDER BY postDate DESC');
                                                                                                                                                            // ^
```

Answer (score 0):

remove semicolon from CURDATE()`;`

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(`postDate`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY postDate DESC');
```

or you can also use `date()` for this

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDate, postStatus, date_accepted FROM blog_posts WHERE postStatus = "pending" AND DATE(`postDate`) = "'.date('Y-m-d').'" ORDER BY postDate DESC');
```